# Remove WordPress default headlines from visual editor

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm wondering if it is possible to remove some of the default headings from the WordPress visual editor to make it easier for my authors to choose the right headings.

[image]

Is it possible to remove for instance "Overskrift 4" and "Overskrift 5"("Heading 4" and "Heading 5") from the list on the image?

Comment: It is possible, there is an existing [filter](http://codex.wordpress.org/TinyMCE#Customize_TinyMCE_with_Filters) for this

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is the code you're looking for, add this to your functions.php file in WordPress. Make sure to edit it to what you want before you save your changes:

```
function wpa_45815($arr){
    $arr['block_formats'] = 'Heading 3=h3;Heading 4=h4'; //change these to what you want before adding this to WordPress
    return $arr;
  }
add_filter('tiny_mce_before_init', 'wpa_45815');
```